How to get most up to date topology json for Highcharts?
I am implementing the World Map Highchart and I am trying to figure out how to ensure I have the most up to date topology json file.
The one I have found is here: https://code.highcharts.com/mapdata/custom/world.topo.json
But that one only has 213 countries listed. Looking at the files I see that it was generated with data from https://www.naturalearthdata.com/
However, looking at their sites they list that there are 258 countries. So it seems like this topology file is not up to date.
Is there one that is?
How is this json file generated, is it a download from their website or you process it?

You can find the most updated maps at https://code.highcharts.com/mapdata/.
The Map Collection is not updated every time the sources change. The sources were initially used to generate the maps in the Map Collection and most of the sources were modified and processed. If you want to use a map based on the most recent version of Natural Earth, you could create a custom map https://www.highcharts.com/docs/maps/create-custom-maps.
You can also create a ticket issue at: https://github.com/highcharts/map-collection-dist. Regards!
